# No Netbeans funciona, no Jar não

Tags: java, mysql, banco-de-dados, jar

Sei que tem alguns tópicos parecidos, mas nenhum responde a minha dúvida.

Criei um programa para inserir informações no banco de dados e ele funciona perfeitamente quando mando o netbeans compilar.

Fiz o Jar, e quando uso o programa a partir do Jar, nada é inserido no banco de dados(MYSQL).

Não entendo a razão disso estar acontecendo.

Comment: Sem um exemplo do seu código fica muito difícil responder a sua dúvida

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Um comando usado pra executar uma classe executável que estava definida como padrão do projeto(a que estava definida como padrão será executada no caso de ter mais de uma classe executável dentro do mesmo jar) é o seguinte:

java -jar nomedoarquivo.jar

Como o autor da pergunta notou, se esse projeto não tiver todas as dependências embutidas, ele precisará fazer referência a onde se encontram as dependências na máquina.

Uma utilidade dos arquivos .jar executáveis é chamá-los via cron para executar tarefas de manutenção do sistema, como geração de relatórios diários, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Consegui resolver, vou deixar aqui para caso alguém também tenha esse problema.

Isso aconteceu porque eu estava usando o JAR fora da pasta dist, e assim perdia a conexão com o banco MYSQL pelo fato de usar um jar externo para a conexao do MYSQL.